# PHP| arrays with times

Tags: php, arrays, unix-timestamp

I need to compare bentween a time taken from a database to the current time.

```
$DBtime = "2013-10-29 17:38:55";
```

this is the format of the arrays in the database.

How can I compare it with the current time?

Im not sure how, but maybe converting DBtime to Unixtime then:

> (CurrentUnixTime - dbUnixTime) = x

Or maybe, we can take the *17:38* and compare it somehow with *date("G:i");*

Thank you! I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform it into a UNIX timestamp using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and then subtract the current timestamp by it.

```
$DBtime = "2013-10-29 17:38:55";
$db_timestamp = strtotime($DBtime);
$now = time();
$difference = $now - $db_timestamp;
echo $difference;
```

This will give you the difference in seconds.

Comment: Thank you for anwsering! I appreciate that.
That was exactly what I looked for...
I knew what I had to do but didn't knew the function ;)
Thanks, I'll use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `DBtime` string to a unix timestamp in PHP using `strtotime`.  In MySQL, you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` when querying the column.

```
time() - strtotime($DBtime)
```

Comment: Wow, what a quick reply!, I appreciate that.
And that function, is amazing! could be so usefull!
I'll surly use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-10-29 17:38:55');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-11-29 18:28:21');
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->format('%m month, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes');
```

Comment: Looks... intresting.
Could you explain me the last two lines?
Thanks.

Comment: @user2054911, `diff` is function of `DateTime` class which `$date1` is object of. It returns an object of `DateInterval` class. Function `format` uses [common date literals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to output what you want in needed format. `->` is used to call functions on objects.

Comment: Sounds intresting and usefull, never heard about it and im going to study abit about it, tx.

Answer (score 0):

```
$DBtime = "2013-10-29 17:38:55";

// Set whatever timezone was used to save the data originally
date_default_timezone_set('CST6CDT');

// Get the current date/time and format the same as your input date
$curdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

if($DBtime == $curdate) {
    // They match, do something
} else {
    // They don't match
}
```